# Task.Factory.StartNew not doing anything

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am trying to start a new task using `Task.Factory`, but it does nothing, as in it just moves to the next line of code and doesn't execute any task. Here is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < alts.Length; i++) {
    String password = alts [i].Substring (alts[i].IndexOf(":")+1);
    String username = alts [i].Substring (0,alts[i].IndexOf(":"));

    Console.WriteLine ("Loaded account: "+ username);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => connectUser(username, password, server));
}
```

Comment: How have you detected that "it does nothing, as in it just moves to the next line of code and doesn't execute any task"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `await` keyword to wait for the task to finish. Just put `await` at the beginning of the line:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => connectUser(username, password, server));
```

Also, you have to add `async` keyword before the return type of the function.

UPDATE (more info):
`Task.Factory.StartNew` creates a task, starts it and returns it to you. When you don't use `await` you don't wait for it to finish. This helps for cases that you want to start a bunch of tasks and let them run simultaneously.

```
    private static void connectUser(string username, string password, string server)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting... " + username);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = "a.com";
        var alts = new string[] { "abc:abc", "bcd:bcd" };

        var tasks = new Task[alts.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < alts.Length; i++)
        {
            String password = alts[i].Substring(alts[i].IndexOf(":") + 1);
            String username = alts[i].Substring(0, alts[i].IndexOf(":"));

            Console.WriteLine("Loaded account: " + username);
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => connectUser(username, password, server));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }
```

This is what I suggested before. You create an array of `Task`s and put the result of `Task.Factory.StartNew()` into that array. You then use the `Task.WaitAll()` function to wait for the tasks to finish. Another approach would be to use threads.

By the way, I suggest you to use Capital letters for function names, meaning: `ConnectUser` instead of `connectUser`.

Comment: Will it not continue looping and start the other "tasks" because the connectUser method eventually turns into an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you want. If you want to run all tasks and wait for them to finish, capture the returned tasks and use [`WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx)

Comment: And if you want to finish them one by one, use the `await` keyword

Comment: Ok, the "task" I am running, is an infinite loop. I just want to be running 3 instances of the infinite loop in the background at the same time, but the program just quits after the task is "registered". (there is no more code in the main method after this loop)

Comment: You need to add something at the end of the program to keep the program running. If it's a console program you can add Console.Readline() or you can wait for all the tasks to finish

Comment: @user1947236 Well, from what you said, `WaitAll` is what you want. I updated the answer and wrote the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, the issue is that Tasks are run on thread pool threads which are background threads. Only foreground threads keep a process running, so once `Main` exits the program ends. You are probably better off just creating the threads manually and setting `IsBackground` to false to keep your program running.